# How do you lock an object to the move tool?

Tags: transforms

I imported part of a Daz Character and moved the origin point to the remaining geometry. When I try to move it, the tool moves away from the object and springs back when releasing the drag. How can I lock the object to the Tool?

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: Thank you. How can I do that. Is it a simple cut and paste like an image?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions)

Comment: I just found the problem inside the item tab. All transforms were locked. Still learning how to use Blender. Maybe I missed a setting in the Daz to Blender bridge.